# Show that the metric induced by a norm $\Delta(x,y)=\|x-y\|$ is a metric

Tags: linear-algebra, metric-spaces

A common way of forming a metric is by using the norm. If $\|\cdot \|$ is a norm, we can verify that $\Delta(x, y)=\|x-y\|$ is a metric by using the properties of a norm to establish the three properties of a metric.

It's a bit embarrassing, but I'm not able to establish the third property: $\Delta(x, y)\le \Delta(x, z)+\Delta(z, y)$.

From the triangle inequality for norms, we have $\Delta(x, y)=\|x-y\|\le\|x\|+\|-y\|=\|x\|+|-1|\|y\|=\|x\|+\|y\|$ for the LHS.

For the RHS, we have $\|x-z\|+\|z-y\|$, however it is unclear this should be any greater than the aforementioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

Observe that $x - y = (x - z) + (z - y)$ and apply the triangle inequality inherited from the norm.

Comment: ahha so do that trick before applying the triangle inequality, nice